# How to make FOR LOOP for changing color of text that has been allready through loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

After searching for hours, I still cant understand how to make this working.

I have some numbers: https://prnt.sc/qaul4u 
and a lop that is increasing number size as you can see on a picture.

I want to make another for lop that is turning PAST numbers in GREEN color, so when that number is over and loop goes to a next, past number turns out to a GREEN color, like a checking algorithm.

MainActivity.java (FOR LOOP)

```
int[] counts;
int currentCount;

TextView countText;

 private void createCountsView() {

        countsList.removeAllViews();

        for(int i = 0; i<counts.length; i++){
            int res = currentCount == i ? R.layout.workout_count_current : R.layout.workout_count;
            View row = inflater.inflate(res,null);
            TextView count = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.w_count_value);
           count.setText(String.valueOf(counts[i]));

            countsList.addView(row);

        }

    }
```

Workout_count.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/w_count_value"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="296dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Workout_count_current.xml - **increasing text size and changing color to white**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/w_count_value"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="296dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```